# ASP.NET redirect. Possible loop?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I want to redirect from all url that contains 'flashmediaelement.swf' to '/mediaplayer/flashmediaelement.swf'. Is it possible that there will be a loop and it will be redirecting without end?
I would use

```
<rule name="Redirect flashmediaelement" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/flashmediaelement.swf$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/mediaplayer/flashmediaelement.swf" />
  </rule>
```

I want to redirect from any pages ending with "/flashmediaelement.swf" (like "mypage.com/blabla/blabla/flashmediaelement.swf" or "mypage.com/flashmediaelement.swf") to "mypage.com/mediaplayer/flashmediaelement.swf"

Answer (score 0):

No , your regular expression  `^/flashmediaelement.swf$` specifies **exact** match for url , so it won't match **'/mediaplayer/flashmediaelement.swf**

See first section [here for **exact match**](https://www.icewarp.com/support/online_help/203030104.htm) regex

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.It edited my question. I want to redirect from any pages ending with "/flashmediaelement.swf" (like "mypage.com/blabla/blabla/flashmediaelement.swf" or "mypage.com/flashmediaelement.swf") to "mypage.com/mediaplayer/flashmediaelement.swf"